# Best library to use for parsing and validating XML in Delphi 7 Pro

Tags: xml, delphi, xslt, xsd, delphi-7

What is the best Delphi 7 Pro library to use for parsing and validating XML?
It seems like more and more XML libraries are not being supported by Delphi 7.

I would like the XML library to:

1. auto generate Delphi 7 class code from the XSD file like I can with C#.
2. auto create XML files from the class code like in C#.
3. use XSLT for XML transformations eventually.
4. use business rules validation like Schematron ideally.
5. other standard things like getting just one XML node or appending a node...

I am willing to purchase a library if not too expensive.

Comment: I don't see why you want code to generate classes when all you really need is a regular XML DOM API like `OmniXML`, plus an XML persistence system that will read/write your class objects to XML. The best code generator is the null code generator, because you don't need to generate code, at all. I'm guessing that `C#` XML feature equivalence for Delphi doesn't exist.  The trouble with code generators is they get out of date and you have to regenerate them, perhaps along with keeping some user-written bits, and such regen-merge cycles suck.

Comment: OmniXML appears to not exist anymore.  http://www.omnixml.com/  I would ideally use a solution with lots of examples, documentation and support.  Especially as needs may grow over time.

Comment: Please take a few minutes to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) - it specifically mentions open-ended discussion type questions as being inappropriate here. You're asking for people's opinions on what is the *best*, which leads to discussions of what's good, bad, etc., and that's not how SO is designed to work. Cooperating with the site guidelines is what keeps SO a valuable (and less noisy) resource.

Comment: If you are willing to purchase anything, then I would highly recommend to purchase Delphi XE2. I was "Stuck" with Delphi 7 for the longest time myself, convinced that it was the "Best Version" until I started using XE2, now I'm convinced that I was just too easily convinced. I say this because XE2 comes with tons of XML stuff (but I have enterprise version, so I'm not sure if it's in other editions)

Comment: OmniXML is free, and open source and has not gone anywhere, and it has lots of examples, documentation and support. http://code.google.com/p/omnixml/

Comment: Good point Jerry! +1 for common sense.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, I believe that Delphi7 contains the `XML databinding wizard`.
The wizard covers points 1,2 and 5.
Make sure you are using [the latest version](http://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/21989&ei=HXuIT_6VN4WUOquRyccJ&usg=AFQjCNFRsIhhcLw_jTogpdbcX29ES-G3Pg&sig2=fa7dYDOop7wPT6ZjNdPdeQ)

Point 3 can be done by free tools like the [MsXML tool from microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb190600.aspx)

**EDIT**

I believe my answer can go down the trash as it does not relate to the OP's delphi version...

Comment: THe XML databinding wizard I heard is only available with the Enterprise version.    And I think the MsXML tool from MS requires Internet Explorer ..? Is that true?

Comment: @user610064 Instead of going by what you hear, you should look yourself. The Databinding Wizard *is* present in Delphi 7 (and 2007). `File->New->VCL Forms Application`, and then `File->New->Other`, choose `Delphi Projects`, then  `XML`, then `XML Data Binding`, and follow the wizard. whosrdaddy, if you want to incorporate the steps I gave to your answer, please do. It will improve it for future readers. :)

Comment: @user610064: indeed my bad, is only for enterprise and architect versions :(. you can download MsXML from the link I posted (maybe IE uses it, but you have it standalone)